# Knockout filtering items using select selectedIndex matching items by id

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I would like to load the second select based on the car make. I am binding the selectedIndexes to ko.observable() variables. I know I can achieve this by using optionsValue : 'id' and binding value to the observable but I need to use selectedIndex in my project. Thank you

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/diegopitt/xg8q5esu/

My viewModel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedIndex = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
             var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
               value(element.selectedIndex);   
            }
        });
    }
};

var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.selectedMake = ko.observable();
    self.selectedType = ko.observable();

    self.makes = [
            {id:1, name: 'Dodge'},
            {id:2, name: 'BMW'}
    ];
    self.types = [
            {id: 1, make:1, name:'neon'},
            {id: 2, make:2, name:'328i'}
    ];
    self.carTypes = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.types, function(item){
            return item.make === self.selectedMake();
        });
    });
    self.matchingTypes = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.carTypes(), function (item, index) {
            return item.id === self.selectedType();
        });
    }); 
};
var model = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

HTML:

```
<select id="make" class="form-control select pull-left" data-bind="options: makes, selectedIndex: selectedMake, optionsText : 'name'"></select>
<select id="type" class="form-control select pull-left" data-bind="options: carTypes, selectedIndex: selectedType, optionsText : 'name'"></select>
```

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/xg8q5esu/1/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since selectedMake is set to the index, the `self.carTypes` computed needs to compare the index instead of the value:

```
self.carTypes = ko.computed(function(){
    var carTypes = [];

    if (self.selectedMake() < self.types.length) {
        carTypes.push(self.types[self.selectedMake()])
    }

    return carTypes;
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2f90w3e/1/)

Comment: still there is an issue select is loading only one item and on first load select is not loading please see friddle http://jsfiddle.net/diegopitt/f2f90w3e/2/

Comment: There is only one type per make and your code is using the change event handler which doesn't fire on load.